# The type or namespace name 'Data' does not exist in the namespace 'Sitecore.Forms'

Tags: sitecore, web-forms-for-marketers

I am using Sitecore 8 and i have installed "Web Forms for Markerter(WFFM)" for create form, I have created custom class

```cs
public class ContactUs : ISaveAction
{
    void ISaveAction.Execute(ID formid, AdaptedResultList fields, params object[] data)
    {
        try
        {
            var submitFields = new NameValueCollection();
            foreach (AdaptedControlResult field in fields)
            {
                submitFields.Add(field.FieldName, field.Value);
            }
            Sitecore.Forms.Data.DataManager.InsertForm(formid, submitFields, Sitecore.Data.ID.NewID, null);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            LogFile("Error" + ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

But it is giving error "The type or namespace name 'Data' does not exist in the namespace 'Sitecore.Forms'"

Comment: What version of WFFM are you using? It looks like the namespaces might have changed in recent versions

Comment: What are you trying to do, save the submitted form fields to the database? It's saved by default to xDB in Sitecore 7.5+

Comment: As Jammykam states you might not need to perform custom logic. However If you are using V.8 for WFFM the namespace `Sitecore.Forms.Data` does not exist in the `Sitecore.Forms.Core.dll`.

The new version of WFFM is now MVC based and all data manager functionality is replaced by `FormDataManager` in the `Sitecore.Forms.Mvc.dll`

Comment: I am using WFFM 8.0 and i am not using MVC. I have created simple form  now i want to save form in sql server database. In WFFM i am not able to see "SaveToDatabase" action so how i can save form in SqlServer? I do not want to save form on mongodb.

Comment: There is no "Save to Database" action anymore, everything is automatically saved to Mongo DB. If you want to save to SQL Server then either create your own handler, or take at look at the [SaveToDatabase Action](http://blog.coates.dk/2014/11/24/sql-provider-for-web-forms-for-marketers-wffm-2-5-sitecore-7-5/) but note that is for Sitecore 7.5 so not sure if it will work in v8